# Jquery mobile screen orientation - Cordova project

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, orientation

I am working on Cordova mobile application with Jquery Mobile and I installed my app on my Android mobile but i do not want the screen orientation in landscape how can i disable this feature in Cordova and Jquery mobile? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Static orientation locking**

If you are using [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), add this to your *config.xml*

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

If not, you need to modify configuration for each platform (*manifest.xml*, *plist*) separately to include directive for this.

For Android, add

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

to activity tag, like this

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

For iOS, add

```
UISupportedInterfaceOrientations
```

with value

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
```

or

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

to *plist*.

**Dynamic orientation locking**

If you instead want to change the orientation per view basis, you can use [Cordova plugin by yoik](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) to adjust the orientations dynamically from your JavaScript code like this

```
screen.lockOrientation("landscape");
```

and unlock with

```
screen.unlockOrientation();
```

Comment: I added it to config.xml but when i run it removed automatically

Comment: Where I should put the screent.lockOrientation("landscape");?

Comment: Depends highly on what you are trying to achieve. If you just want to lock the orientation for whole app to landscape, you should use the static methods offered. If you instead want only some views to be locked to landscape, you should call the _screen.lockOrientation("landscape");_ when you want to lock it, for example on _deviceReady_ event or whenever you wish to lock the orientation.

Comment: Did you add it to your _deviceReady_ handler? If so, are you sure it is been executed at all? You can check it by doing `alert("deviceReady")` inside the callback.